# Problems with simple preg_replace + RegEx

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Please pardon the fact that I am a complete newbie to RegEx, and have not really used preg_replace before.

I'm trying to take a string and replace any occurrences of "(username) said:" with "@(username)\n". Since usernames can only have spaces, letters, and numbers, I used [A-Za-z0-9\s]. However, it isn't working, and I know I did something wrong:

`$message = preg_replace("/([A-Za-z0-9\s]*) said:", "@$0\n", $message);`

Is this the proper way to use preg_replace, or is there a different way I should be going about this?

Comment: The error message says: `No ending delimiter '/' found`. Enable error_reporting. Otherwise the regex is correct. It doesn't cut out the `said:` part however.

Comment: Thanks for that info, it worked. This operation was being performed right before a redirect so I didn't see the error, nor did I expect one. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close to the answer. The main problem is that the [end delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (/) was missing. Below is the regex that I would recommend:

```
<?php
$string = '(username) said:';
$string = preg_replace('#(\([A-Za-z0-9\s]+\)) said:#',"@$1\n", $string);
echo $string;
?>
```

I also used a + instead of a * as plus means the characters need to happen one or more times (instead of 0 or more times). The $0 will match the entire search pattern (including the word said) but you just wanted to match the username which is a group in parenthesis so I used $1. I also escaped parenthesis as `\(\)` as your example has username in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

$message = 'some said:';

$message = preg_replace("/(.*)\ssaid:/Ui", "REPLACE said:", $message);
echo $message;